# SafeNet Sentinel RMS server needs to be pinged before it works (routed across VLANs)

Tags: router, vlan, ping

I have 2 separate CAD programs that use the Safenet Sentinel RMS Server (Aladdin) to check the license.

After boot, they cannot find the license server.
The license server is configured using its ip address.
After I ping the license server's ip, everything works normally.

After some time, it doesn't work anymore until I ping the server again.
The client PC is in VLAN 104, the license server is in VLAN 101.

Traffic gets routed by Microsoft TMG server.
Pinging another ip in VLAN 101 does not help, it has to be the IP of the license server.

The client runs windows 10 pro.

What can I do to make it work without having to ping first?

Comment: That's not nearly enough information sorry.

Comment: If you can tell me what more information you would like, I will gladly provide it.

Comment: Scheduled task to ping the IP once an hour.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you have an IP address conflict, the next time it's not working before you ping it look at your arp cache `arp-a` and note down the MAC address, now ping the RMS server and look in the arp cache again

Comment: No ARP entries found.

Comment: When I open the license manager, the entry for the server is there, and when I click it, it should contact the server and show me the available licenses. It times out and if I do arp -a again, it still says no arp entries found. It is as if it doesn't try to find the ip.

Comment: When I ping 8.8.8.8 it also doesn't create an arp entry, so I guess that's normal for an ip that's not in the same subnet? It has to go through the gateway in order to reach it.